# Problems with internet connection and mouse cursor Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, mouse, cursor

Hi I know there are some other questions concerning similar themes, but I cannot get a answer to my problems. I´ve searched all around the internet and cannot find an answer. I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit to my Lenovo thinkpad T400. As soon as the installation finishes and I restart the computer, the internet connection fails. The ethernet connection doesn`t even appear. So I am not able to connect to the internet. The other problem is with the mouse cursor. At the beginning it appears but freezes and afterwards it simply disappears. I`ve tried the solution with the displays but in my case it doesn´t appear a second display. I also tried typing sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse into the terminal but no success. And also typing other things into the terminal. I don´t know if simply my computer is too old for ubuntu 14.04 64 bits. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the Wi-Fi problem you have a link here:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220169

But for the mouse cursor you have one link here:http://jiakaizhang.com/fix-frozen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04/

And another one here:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136555/ubuntu-14-04-mouse-pointer-does-not-move

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Please leave a note @Fabby after you've done this and you'll see a +12 instead of a -2 to your reputation!